# www.baidu.com can be visited but unable to be ping or tracert

Tags: networking, tcp, ping

My computer is in intranet. I can visit www.baidu.com , see 
[image]

But it is unable to ping  or tracert , see 
[image]

[image]

Could anyone explain why  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many ISPs filter out ICMP (which is what ping/tracert on windows uses). It can also be that your router @home does only partial NAT of your connections and only allows some standard user protocols like HTTP/FTP/whatnot.

There's nothing to be alarmed of really, it's fairly normal, so unless you have a particular reason you want this to work - it should have no impact on your browsing experience.

Answer (score 0):

They (or your intranet or someone in between) could block ping messages and still serve HTTP.

FWIW I can ping them just fine (but the IP address is different):

```
$ ping www.baidu.com
PING www.a.shifen.com (119.75.217.56): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 119.75.217.56: icmp_seq=0 ttl=55 time=28.041 ms
64 bytes from 119.75.217.56: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=29.468 ms
64 bytes from 119.75.217.56: icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=26.807 ms
```